# input mask for UK company registration number

Tags: regex, jquery-inputmask

A UK company registration number for England and Wales consists of 8 integers.
For Scotland it is "SC" followed by 6 integers, and for Northern Ireland it is "NI" followed by 6 integers.
The documentation for input mask is comprehensive, see http://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask.
And the easiest solution is;

```
$("input.CompanyFormat").inputmask("**999999",  "placeholder": "", "casing": "upper" });
```

But this is not the best solution. The user should only be able to enter "SC", "NI" or 2 digits followed by 6 digits.

Comment: What if you replace `"**999999"` with `{ regex: "^(SC|NI|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{6}$" }`?

Comment: That didn't work although I thank you for the regex. What I can do is use my original mask, and then do a validation check using your regex in the focusout event.

Comment: I think you can use Wiktors first regex but without the `^` and `$`

Comment: @Fallenhero That is true if the pattern is used in the `pattern` attribute.

Comment: Ok, got it, it is the usual problem with input masks: the single char input is totally unaware of the context. Thus, you can't even define a multicharacter pattern for a wildcard. You really have to use an additional validation mechanism along with the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the regex approach common to all input masks: the single char input is totally unaware of the context. You can only define a special pattern for a single char input, e.g. if you want the first char to be `S`, you may define it inside `definitions`, but it will be unaware of what will go after it or what precedes it.

Thus, you can't define a multicharacter pattern for a wildcard and you have to use an additional validation mechanism along with the mask.

E.g. you may use an input HTML5 `pattern` validation to tell the user the pattern is not valid:

```
<input type="text" pattern="(SC|NI|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{6}" title="Wrong input!">
```

See the HTML5 demo:

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="(SC|NI|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{6}" title="Wrong input!" />
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

The `pattern="(SC|NI|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{6}"` (it will compile as `/^(?:(SC|NI|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{6})$/`, with `u` modifier in FF and Chrome) will match any input that matches

- `^` - start of string (implicit)
- `(SC|NI|[0-9]{2})` - `SC`, `NI` or 2 digits
- `[0-9]{6}` - 6 digits
- `$` - end of string (implicit).